# Resize MTD partitions at runtime

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, partitioning

I am working with embedded devices and would like to enable them to resize their MTD partitions via Linux without rebooting.

The problem is that my Linux image size has increased and the current MTD partition (mtd0) in which it resides is now too small. However, the partition right after it (mtd1) is a JFFS2 section used for storing config information, so resizing with a reboot is not an option because the config could be lost.

My goal is this:

```
1. Copy contents of JFFS2 into /tmp/
2. Unmount JFFS2 from mtd1
3. Increase the starting offset + reduce size of mtd1 by X bytes (or delete mtd1 and create new mtd of proper size and offset)
4. Mount JFFS2 on new mtd1 and restore contents from /tmp/
5. Increase the size of mtd0 by X bytes
6. Burn new (larger) Linux image into mtd0 (the new image will contain a device tree with an updated partition structure)
7. Reboot
```

I found a proposed patch to "mtd-utils" from a couple years back:

```
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.mtd/30949
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.mtd/30950
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.mtd/30951
```

Using this as a guide I was able to write kernel and user-space code to create a new MTD partition on which I can mount JFFS2. However, this code does not properly delete partitions. Even after unmounting JFFS2 from mtd1 and calling `put_mtd_device`, when `del_mtd_device` is called the kernel complains:

```
user.notice kernel: Removing MTD device #1 (jffs2) with use count 1
```

What I'd like to know is:

```
1. How to fix the patch to allow deleting my old mtd1
2. How to change the starting offset of mtd1 instead of creating/deleting partitions
```

I tried contacting the author of the patch, but their email is no longer valid, so I would appreciate any suggestions!

---

**UPDATE:**

It seems that `mtd_open()` in `mtdchar.c` triggers a `get_mtd_device()`, which probably accounts for the extra `usecount` increment. But my userspace app needs to call `open()` on the partition to send it an `ioctl()` for deleting a partition :/ catch 22? Is there a more correct way of doing this?

Comment: Perhaps you could instrument the code to indicate incrementing and decrementing of the reference count and figure out where it gets off (I assume it's not your root filesystem...)  As an alternative idea, maybe you could shrink the image size by removing unneeded functionality or moving some to a module.  Or have an intermediate upgrade using a stripped down image which backs up the config information elsewhere permitting you to then recreate the file system upon booting the new full image.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I like the idea of trying to track down the reference counts, I will try that next. Shrinking the image is not an option, I've already done a whole lot of work to make it as small as it is right now, and I'm working on a big project that may increase the size by as much as 50% (too early to tell at this point). I really need a way to expand the partition to handle this in the future. I've also thought about using an intermediate location, but the upgrade will need to be done remotely in a variety of network configuration, so I'm afraid this would be too complex/unreliable.

Comment: It seems that in `mtdchar.c` the `mtd_open()` triggers a `get_mtd_device()`, which probably accounts for the extra `usecount` increment. But my userspace app needs to call `open()` on the partition to send it an `ioctl()` for deleting a partition :/ catch 22? Is there a more correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by having my patched mtd utility increase "mtd0" size, then create a brand new partition of the correct reduced size to mount JFFS on, which gave me a chance to copy the config info into the new flash location.

To reduce complexity, I also made it so I couldn't run this app more than once. It ended up being a "run once, do your thing, reboot" type of procedure.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's my code, figured it could benefit some folks:

https://github.com/mikzat/mtd_runtime_partition